# Unable to perform SNMP GET using snmpget CLI command but able to perform SNMP GET using MIB browser

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I was configuring my SNMP agent on a Linux machine, below is the user-defined settings which I have included in the default *snmpd.conf* settings.

```
rwuser bootstrap priv
rwuser prateek priv

createUser bootstrap SHA temp_password AES
```

I then restarted the SNMP service and then tried to perform SNMP GET on sysDescr OID and was able to perform is successful.

[image: screenshot 1]

I then tried to same with snmpget CLI command,

```
snmpget -v 3 -u bootstrap -l authPriv -a SHA -x AES -A temp_password -X temp_password 127.0.0.1:161 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
```

but I get the below error.

```
Timeout: No Response from 127.0.0.1:161
```

**NOTE**: SNMP client and agent are running on same host.

Can anyone explain to me why I am unable to perform the same operation which I am able to perform using MIB browser?

Comment: You'd better run the agent on another machine, so that you can use tools like Wireshark to easily analyze network packets.

Answer (score 0):

The address 127.0.0.1 means you MUST be running the SNMPGET on the same system
as the agent, and you have not proven that.

Also, the error message should be "127.0.0.1:161", so either the edit is mistaken,
or the command is mistaken. Inconsistencies like this usually points to user error.

Comment: I have updated the question with more information you needed and corrected the port to 161 in the error. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: If you add the -d option it enables debugging. Look at the man page for the client, there are more levels of debugging. That should point out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I tried it but I am not able to get something meaningful looking at which I can get an idea of what I am missing. Below is the brief output of the error when I ran the command in debug mode
https://pastebin.com/7muBuHKU

Comment: Also, I have verified that snmpd daemon is listening on port 161 using netstat command.
[prateek@fedora ~]$ netstat -anp | grep 161
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:161             0.0.0.0:*

Comment: Obviously you are doing something wrong that you are not showing. Enable debugging in your snmpd and it might tell you more. Else, get it working with less complication, ie. noAuthNoPriv, then authNoPriv, etc. It is ALWAYS easier, faster to start from success than from failure.